# What is the idiomatic way to package these classes in Java

Tags: java, namespaces, package

I'm writing a library which has like 25 classes. 4-5 of them are meant to be a public api. The other classes are package private at the moment. My problem is that I want to arrange them to their own packages but this is not possible with the current setup because that way those classes won't be able to see each other.

So should I just leave them as-is without arrangement or make them all `public` so I can rearrange them? The latter I think is not a good solution because a lot of classes are not meant to be used by the end user but I don't like them just dumped into a root package as it will only grow in size.

Is there an idiomatic way in java to solve this problem?

**Example:**

I have a class named `HexagonalGridBuilder`. It is public and part of the api. Same stands for `HexagonOrientation` which is an enum and holds the value of (`FLAT_TOP` and `POINTY_TOP`) and `HexagonalGridLayout` which is an enum as well and holds the values for the types of hexagonal grids like `RECTANGULAR` and `TRIANGULAR`. The end user can use those enums to parametrize the `HexagonalGridBuilder` object which reuturns a `HexagonalGrid` which is an interface.

All of the implementation classes are package private like `HexagonalGridImpl` or `TriangularGridLayoutStrategy`. I can't move these classes into different packages without making them all `public` because of this packaging problem I described.

Comment: Give us an example. I'm pretty sure a mix of protected and proper packaging would fix this.

Comment: I am of the opinion that if one class needs to talk to another in a way different to the way everyone else should be able to talk to it (which includes a lack of ability to talk to it, as in your case), they should be in the same package / namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside for waiting for Java Project jigsaw there are several work arounds to your solution:

1. Keep the code as is with package-private classes, users won't see these so only you will be bothered by lots of classes in the package.
2. You can make packages with names like my.package.internal but have the classes public so they could be usable by others, but hopefully the name "internal" tells them not to.
3. Use something like OSGI which can enforce public vs private API and not let others ourside your jar directly access classes you don't want them to.  However, this will only be enforced if your users are also using OSGI.

Comment: I want to keep the dependencies to a minimum. In fact currently there is only one barrier a future user can bump into: the project uses maven but apart from that there is no dependency to anything outside the java api. I don't want to raise any barriers so OSGI is not an option here.

Comment: I recommend a combination of 2 and 3 above. Put the non-API classes in "internal" packages, and include OSGi directives in your MANIFEST.MF so that only the public packages are exported when the library is used with OSGi. Making your library OSGi compliant in this way does not require introducing any dependencies. The maven-bundle-plugin will even help generate the MANIFEST for you.

Comment: That seems like a good idea. I think I'll read about OSGI because I don't know much about it.